# infragistics UltraMaskedEdit character alignment issue

Tags: infragistics

We have used the UltraMaskedEdit control for several years. Suddenly characters change vertical alignment in our strings. In other words if you type "123" the "1" is sometimes shifted up in the string a few pixels. A little testing revealed that the character is actually at the top of the space occupied by all the characters in the font while the un-shifted characters occupy the middle of the font space. Has anyone else seen and fixed this issue? The control is part of a winforms app that has been in production for quite a while, this behavior is very recent however. Thanks

Comment: Probably better to submit a small example app to Infragistics in a support request or on their help forums.